# Manually connecting and disconnecting bindings

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm creating a form with fields for billing and shipping addresses.  When the user checks "same address", I want to create a binding between the billing address and shipping address; when the box is unchecked, I want to disconnect that binding.

**HTML:**

```
{{#with billingAddress}}
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="firstName"}}
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="lastName"}}
{{/with}}

{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="view.isSameAddress"}}

{{#with shippingAddress}}
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="firstName"}}
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="lastName"}}
{{/with}}
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
App.AddressesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      billingAddress: Checkout.BillingAddress,
      shippingAddress: Checkout.ShippingAddress
    };
  }
});

App.AddressesView = Ember.View.extend({
  isSameAddress: false,
  useSameAddress: function() {
    if (this.isSameAddress) {
      // bind billing and shipping addresses
    } else {
      // remove binding
    }
  }.observes('isSameAddress')
});

App.Address = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null
});

App.Billing = App.Address.create({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe'
});

App.Shipping = App.Address.create({
  firstName: '',
  lastName: ''
});
```

I've tried using `Ember.Binding`, as well as a number of other methods with no luck. I've been able to set the shipping as the billing, but there is no binding and the template does not update.

Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: how have you tried using `Ember.Binding`? can you show what did not work? or what other methids

Comment: here is more info on connect and disconnect bindings https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/binding.js#L148

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not Ember expert but seems like you need to use [Ember.Binding](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Binding.html). Maybe something like this:

```
Ember.oneWay(App.Shipping, "firstName", "App.Billing.firstName");
```

to set up one way binding between `App.Shipping.firstName` and `App.Billing.firstName` fields.

http://jsfiddle.net/mSxeP/1/